# Using passport-steam with sails-generate-auth

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, passport.js

I'm creating a SailsJS application, and I want users to log in only with Steam authentication. I used `sails-generate-auth` to create some boilerplate code with sails routes, but I'm having trouble plugging passport-steam into it.

https://github.com/kasperisager/sails-generate-auth

https://github.com/liamcurry/passport-steam

The reported error is:

```
C:\Users\Joe\testProject\node_modules\passport-steam\lib\passport-steam\strategy.js:67
            id: result.response.players[0].steamid,
                                          ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'steamid' of undefined
    at steamapi.getPlayerSummaries.callback (C:\Users\Joe\testProject\node_modules\passport-steam\lib\passport-steam\strategy.js:67:43)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Joe\testProject\node_modules\passport-steam\node_modules\steam-web\lib\steam.js:218:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:944:16
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:486:13)
```

I have a feeling that this is caused by SteamWebAPI returning an empty response: `{"response":{"players":[]}}`, which is caused by a bogus SteamID in the request. The offending line is here in passport-steam: https://github.com/liamcurry/passport-steam/blob/master/lib/passport-steam/strategy.js#L53

Looking at `identifier` parameter to `getUserProfile`, it appears to be the entire Sails request scope. If I hardcode a good steam id into that array, I get this error:

```
C:\Users\Joe\testProject\api\services\passport.js:98
    return next(new Error('Neither a username nor email was available'));
           ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Authenticator.passport.connect (C:\Users\Joe\testProject\api\services\passport.js:98:12)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Joe\testProject\api\services\protocols\openid.js:24:12)
    at steamapi.getPlayerSummaries.callback (C:\Users\Joe\testProject\node_modules\passport-steam\lib\passport-steam\strategy.js:72:11)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Joe\testProject\node_modules\passport-steam\node_modules\steam-web\lib\steam.js:218:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:944:16
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:486:13)
```

I think that makes sense since the steam response doesn't have a username nor email, but this is the profile: `{"emails":[{}],"name":{}}`

This is my passport configuration:

```
steam: {
    name: 'Steam',
    protocol: 'openid',
    strategy: require('passport-steam').Strategy,
    options: {
      returnURL: 'http://localhost:1337/auth/steam/callback',
      realm: 'http://localhost:1337/',
      apiKey:'STEAM-API-KEY-REMOVED'
      }
    }
  }
```

Not sure if there is something simple I'm missing, or I need to write a ton of custom handling. Is my configuration correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by out-of-date source code in npm. Even with the latest 0.1.4 version, the code is not correct. Replacing `strategy.js` in passport-steam with the [latest version](https://github.com/liamcurry/passport-steam/blob/master/lib/passport-steam/strategy.js) will fix this error.

Also, in `api\services\passport.js`, a little custom handling in `passport.connect()` needs to be added. The `profile` does not have a `username`, but has an `id` (user steamid) and `displayName`. These can be used to set the user model properties, e.g.

```
//steam auth
if (profile.hasOwnProperty('displayName')) { 
  user.username = profile.displayName; 
}
```

Here is the ticket where the problem was solved: https://github.com/liamcurry/passport-steam/issues/10

Comment: I'm new to Sails/Passport/Steam login. Bottom line, where do I put this code? Can anyone upload a git with Sails new project, and just the Steam login code added?

Comment: The passport-steam npm module should be up to date. You need to add that tiny bit of code above to `api/services/passport.js: connect function`. The `profile` object should have the data returned from the Steam API, so you can get steam id, avatar image, etc..

You also need to add the Steam Passport config to `config/passport.js`. The first post shows a boilerplate object to paste into `module.exports.passport = { /* STEAM CONFIG HERE */ }`

I have not used Sails in a few months, so I am unsure if this advice is completely correct.