# how to use sails-generate-auth (e.g. for steam login)

Tags: sails.js, passport.js, steam, steam-web-api, steamworks-api

Can you please provide a clear, specific example on how to use sails-generate-auth using a particular login system, like that of steampowered?

The instructions for using sails-generate-auth are too general and lack specific examples for even 1 login system (e.g. facebook, twitter, steam, etc)

https://github.com/kasperisager/sails-generate-auth

I'm trying to login to steam. Here is a module that should help with that: https://github.com/liamcurry/passport-steam

This guy talks about doing this, but it's not clear to me what he's done to even get as far as he has: [Using passport-steam with sails-generate-auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27806291/using-passport-steam-with-sails-generate-auth)

Thanks!